# How read all files from azure blob storage in C# Core

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to read files from an azure blob storage (the files inside the folder), the blob storage contains many folders.
I want to read my folder 'blobstorage' ,it contains many JSON files performing .read to each file and some manipulations. I tried many code that did not work:

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference($"blobstorage");
```

The above code uses 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' nuget package. This code is not working as expected.
In many questions and answers found in stack overflow I found that most of them are outdated and does not work.
Note: if any nuget mention that also bcs they are many packages

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution in this [post](https://www.pritambaldota.com/reading-string-content-from-azure-blob-storage-using-csharp/) and worked perfectly for me. You just have to read it as a normal stream after the download.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionString");
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("blobName.csv");
if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
{
  var response = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
  using (var streamReader= new StreamReader(response.Value.Content))
  {
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
      var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
      Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Working, but Performance of this code is very poor.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any option to list all blob using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package. If you can use `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package then try below code.

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storage******c9709;AccountKey=v**************************************;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        static string container = "azure-webjobs-hosts";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get a reference to a container named "sample-container" and then create it
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, container);
            blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
            Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs...");
            // List all blobs in the container
            var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs();
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
            }            
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

You can also download the content of blob, Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#list-the-blobs-in-a-container)

Comment: its just listing all files. i want read all files from specific folder

Comment: You can also download content of blob check updated answer, I added link

Comment: i don't  all blob, only specified folder files and read filecontent, download is not possible

Comment: folder inside a container is just virtual folder, You can read all file and folder from particular container then you can filter and download only required folder JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mass data to download and are looking for efficiency, you probably don't want to download them 1 by 1 on a single thread. Use multiple threads and async.

Here's a good read on the topic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-download-files?tabs=dotnet

downloading 1000 files:

- with single-thread : 30seconds download time
- with multi-thread  :  4seconds download time

Answer (score 0):

You can find example code in the SDK github repo here for c#:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Storage.Blobs_12.8.0/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/

You can use the following command to add the package to your dotNet Core project.

```
dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Blobs
```

Based on the examples there, you can enumerate the blobs and then read the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code Out :

var connectionString = "your connection string";

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        //Create Reference to Azure Blob
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containerName");
        var blobs = container.GetDirectoryReference("FolderName").GetDirectoryReference("FolderName").ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Total files found in directory: " + blobs.Count.ToString());
        var tempBlobList = blobs.Where(b => b.Name.Contains("fileName")).ToList();
        var response = await tempBlobList[0].DownloadTextAsync();
```